# Flutter change text color on active ExpensionTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to change ExpensionTile text color on active?

[image]

This is the ExpensionTile I'm trying to change, as you can see the current color is purple.

This is the code:

```
ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text('Current Version',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15
                      ),),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            'Version 0.1',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set change the text color of the [`ExpansionTile()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html), you can use the [`textColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/textColor.html) property:

> The color of the tile's titles when the sublist is expanded.

Usage:

```
textColor: Colors.green
```

In your example:

```
ExpansionTile(
      textColor: Colors.green,
                    title: Text('Current Version',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15
                      ),),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            'Version 0.1',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
```